# QT Bluetooth PAN

Tags: qt, bluetooth

i am trying to create a Bluetooth PAN manager application in QT.I tried to connect to Bluetooth NAP service in android phone using [QBluetoothSocke](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qtmobility-1.2/qbluetoothsocket.html)t class.

```
if (socket)
        return;

    // Connect to service
    QBluetoothUuid uuid( QBluetoothUuid::NAP);

    socket = new QBluetoothSocket(QBluetoothServiceInfo::RfcommProtocol);
    qDebug() << "Create socket"<<remoteDevice;


     socket->connectToService(remoteDevice,uuid);
     qDebug() << socket->peerAddress();
     if ( !socket->isOpen() )
      {
            qDebug() << "Error Unabel to open socket" ;

      }
     qDebug() << "ConnectToService done";
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readSocket()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(connected()), this, SLOT(connected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SIGNAL(disconnected()));
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(error(QBluetoothSocket::SocketError)), this, SLOT(connectionError()));
```

QBluetoothSocket's `connected()` signal is emited but i can't access my phone's internet connection. please help me to figure out the problem.I am using Ubuntu 14.10